# How to prevent repeated processing in Flask

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I have a site in production using: Flask, Gunicorn, MongoEngine and I'm facing duplicate data processing error due to too many requests per second on certain routes.

**Example code:**

```py
@app.route('/proccess_data/<u_id>')
def procces_dt_(u_id):

    check_exists = db_collection.find_one({'u_id': u_id})
    if not check_exists:
        db_collection.insert_one({
            'u_id': u_id,
            'key': 'value'
        })
        return 'OK'
    else:
        return 'has already been processed', 403
```

See this check I do in the database before inserting a new document. This seems correct to me.

But I tested a few requests per second and the result is multiple identical documents inserted.

Making it clear that for me it would not be useful just to create a unique index for a field: u_id

I've already tested some things I researched, but nothing works and I also didn't find many things related to it.

Comment: seems like a common concurrency issue. Why creating a unique index is not useful to you? It is the most direct solution. It also saves you a (costly) db call for checking the existence in the sense that you can directly insert the record and let the index block the duplicate for you.

Comment: Hi Ray.

I had a smattering of index knowledge in mongodb. After your answer, I went to study a little more about indexes and realized that I could create [Composite Indexes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-compound/), and that does solve my problem :)

Before, I thought that indexes could only be created on one field at a time, so it didn't meet my needs.

Thanks for your help!